# Change the value of an input in html using MEAN stack

Tags: javascript, html, angular, web, mean-stack

I'm using MEAN stack for the first time and I'm having a problem updating the value of inputs in a form. I want to click a button and put some values in the inputs. The problem is that even if I do change the value of the input doing: `document.getElementById('name').value =name;`
The value changes but the form doesn't detect the change and can't send the data.

Here is the code of the form:

```
<form #placeForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="addPlace(placeForm)" >
            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s4">
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" #name="ngModel"  [(ngModel)]="placeService.selectedPlace.name" >
                    <label for="name">Nombre del establecimiento</label>
                  </div>      
              <div class="input-field col s4">
                <input type="text" name="city" id="locality" #city="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="placeService.selectedPlace.city">
                  <label for="city">Ciudad</label>
              </div>
                <div class="input-field col s8">
                    <button class="waves-effect waves-light btn right"  onclick=" M.toast({html: 'Información introducida en la BD', classes: 'rounded green'});"><i class="material-icons right">add</i>Guardar</button>

                </div>

            </div>
          </form>
```

Here is the class placeService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Place } from '../models/place';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PlaceService {
  selectedPlace: Place;
  places: Place[];
  readonly URL_API = 'http://localhost:3000/places';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
    this.selectedPlace= new Place();
  }

  getPlaces() {
    return this.http.get(this.URL_API);
    //.subscribe()
  }
}
```

Comment: What version of Angular are you using?  The `angularjs` tag is for Angular 1.x, but this looks like a later version.

Comment: Angular 7.1.4, sorry, I've changed the tag.

Comment: You're using document.getelement to change value? That's not going to work. You need to change the value with what you have assigned on the ngModel

Comment: @penleychan how would be the code to change it with ngModel? I have trieddoing this: `placeService.selectedPlace.name = name` but doesn't work neither

Comment: If you update the model outside of Angular's digest loop, you have to signal to Angular that it needs to perform a digest loop.  I don't know how to do that in Angular 2+ though, so I can't help further.

Comment: Are you using standard Angular convention for your form? i.e. does it have a accompanying `form.component.ts` and `form.component.css`?

Comment: @Milo I'm not doing it with a component, its just the code shown above on HTML